# Не корректно выводится дата

Tags: php

У меня нарисовалась мелкая, но неприятная помарка при выводе даты. На странице меток пункты списка должны выглядеть так:

> 26, Июнь, 2017 - Заголовок статьи ; 13, Июнь, 2017 - Заголовок статьи

а отображается таким образом:

> 026, Июнь, 2017 - Заголовок статьи ; 1213, Июнь, 2017 - Заголовок статьи.

К сожалению текущие познания в php не позволяют мне самостоятельно разобраться с проблемой, да и метод тыка на сей раз не помог. За сим прилагаю код:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><span class="comments_number"><?php comments_number('0', '1', '%', ''); ?></span><span class="archdate"><?php the_time(__ ('j, F, Y', 'punchcut')) ?> - </span><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Comment: найдите код функции `the_time()` там косяк какой-то.

Comment: а не, у вас там перед датой число комментариев просто выводится. 0 и 12 соответственно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <!--
    <span class="comments_number">
        <?php comments_number('0', '1', '%', ''); ?>
    </span>
    -->
    <span class="archdate">
        <?php the_time(__ ('j, F, Y', 'punchcut')) ?> - 
    </span>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</a>
```